# How do I create a user account for basic authentication?

Tags: iis, iis-7, basic-authentication

I'd like to add basic authentication to my website. I followed the instructions in the MSDN article on [Configure Basic Authentication (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772009.aspx)

> #### To use the UI
>
> 1. Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level you want to manage. For information about opening IIS Manager, see [Open IIS Manager (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770472.aspx). For information about navigating to locations in the UI, see [Navigation in IIS Manager (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732920.aspx).
> 2. In **Features View**, double-click **Authentication**.
> 3. On the **Authentication** page, select **Basic Authentication**.
> 4. In the **Actions** pane, click **Enable** to use Basic authentication with the default settings.
> 5. Optionally, in the **Actions** pane, click **Edit** to type the default domain and realm.
> 6. In the **Edit Basic Authentication Settings** dialog box, in the **Default domain** text box, type a default domain or leave it blank. Users who do not provide a domain when they log on to your site are authenticated against this domain.
> 7. In the **Realm** text box, type a realm or leave it blank. In general, you can use the same value for the realm name as you used for the default domain.
>
>    - **Important**
>        If you enter the default domain name in the Realm text box, your internal Microsoft Windows domain name may be exposed to external users during the user name and password challenge.
> 8. Click **OK** to close the **Edit Basic Authentication Settings** dialog box.

Here's what I've done so far:

[image: IIS Manager - Authentication]
[image: Authentication Page - Basic Authentication]

Now I need to create a user account for the basic authentication.

Does anyone know how to create users in IIS Manager?

Comment: were you able to get the solution for this?

Answer (score 89):

Right click on Computer and choose "Manage" (or go to Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Computer Management) and under "Local Users and Groups" you can add a new user. Then, give that user permission to read the directory where the site is hosted.

**Note:** After creating the user, be sure to edit the user and remove all roles.

Comment: This is sub-ideal because it creates a vector for attack, allowing users to log into my machine. The approach where "IIS Management User" is created that has no login or local priveleges on my windows machine is superior.

Comment: @WarrenP - No, you just remove all roles from the user after creation and they can't login or do anything you don't specifically give them permission to do.

Comment: So a local user account with no roles can not do anything? Good. The default role "local user" is the one granting login, and can be removed.

Comment: @WarrenP - that is my understanding. And regardless, you should be setting a strong password on the user account.

Comment: I need to add this here because it took me some time to find it, after creating the user and removing all the roles as suggested by Josh M you need to change the general setting because by default the User must change password at next logon will be ticked and this will cause an issue, so what you want is to un-tick this and tick User cannot change password.

Answer (score 28):

I know this is a really old question but I wanted to add a bit of explanation that I discovered the hard way (this is n00b information).

"Basic Authentication" shares the same accounts that you have on your local computer or network. If you leave the domain and realm empty, local accounts are what are actually being used. So to add a new account you follow the exact process you would for adding a normal new user account to your local computer (as answered by JoshM or [shown here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-user-account#create-user-account=windows-7)). If you enter a domain and realm you can create network accounts in your local active directory and these are what will be used to log the user in and out.

Because it has been around for so long, basic authentication is generally compatible with any browser/system out there but it does have to major flaws:

- user and password are sent in the clear (except over SSL)
- you need to have a user account for each user or client

For more information about basic authentication or user accounts see [the following MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292114%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Again,. this is sub-ideal.  Does nobody worry about security here?

Comment: @drew_w, I am using IIS basic auth, can you explain the Default Domain when making the configuration? Does it work with Active Directory?

Comment: @WarrenP for security, I think you can try Basic Authentication + SSL.

Answer (score 16):

I was able to achieve Basic Authentication on **Windows Server 2012** doing the following:

Select your site within IIS and choose **Authentication**
[image]

Ensure **Basic Authentication** is the only enabled option
[image]

THEN! Add a username and password via the **Server Manager**.
Select **Tools** -> **Computer Management**
[image]

Under **System Tools** -> **Local Users and Groups** -> **Users** right-click anywhere in the middle pane, choose **New User..** then fill in the credentials you want to use.
[image]

Now when you navigate to the site in the browser you should get prompted with an authentication dialog:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

If you create a user with the advanced user management (from command line: `netplwiz`), then modify the group, remove users, and add iis_users. They will be able to authenticate to your web page, but not the computer.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was searching for. The group is called "`IIS_IUSRS`" on local machines, though.

Comment: IIS_IUSRS is not the correct group for this. "IIS_IUSRS is a built-in group has access to all the necessary file and system resources so that an account, when added to this group, can seamlessly act as an application pool identity."

Comment: There's no `iis_users` group on my Windows Server 2012 install.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunatelly, for IIS installed on Windows 7/8 machines, there is no option to create users only for IIS authentification. 
For Windows Server there is that option where you can add users from IIS Manager UI. These users have roles only on IIS, but not for the rest of the system. 
[In this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732621%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) it shows how you add users, but it is incorrect stating that is also appliable to standard OS, it only applies to server versions.

Comment: when I create a local user, how do I use it in basic auth then? My created user is not recognized

Comment: Dont't forget to enable  Basic authentification in IIS Server.

Comment: According to here (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771311%28v=WS.10%29.aspx), the IIS Manager User is not a normal user. I think it's for management purpose. For adding user for basic Authentication, I agree with drew_w's answer.

Comment: I don't think IIS Manager is meant for normal use.

Comment: Can not authenticated when use IIS manager user for Basic Authentication

Comment: I don't know how this has gotten any upvotes.  IIS Manager users are for the WMI service, not HTTP Basic auth.  WMI is used for many things, such as publishing web apps via Web Deploy.  Frontend user authentication is not one of those things.

Comment: This answer is simply wrong. You cannot use IIS Manager users for Basic Authentication. You can use them for FTP auth, though.

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like Windows 8 and IIS 7 no longer provides any UI to create a user name and password for basic authentication that is NOT a windows local user account.  It is clearly a superior approach to create an IIS-only user/password authentication pair, but it is not clear and easy how it is done.

Command line tools exist for this purpose.  Some people create a Windows account and then remove the Log on Locally User Privilege.

Answer (score 1):

Configure basic authentication using the instructions from [microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772009%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). But for the Default Domain Name, type your computer name. To find your computer name, click start, right-click computer, click properties, and search for your computer name there :)

Next, create users like you would normally do on windows 7. or if you don't know how to do it, go control-panel, users, add account.....blah blah blah.... Get It?

Next go to iis and set permissions for the user you just created. Be carefull to set the permissions to make it exactly how you want it.

That's all! To login, the username and password!

NOTE: The username should be simple letters, not capital. I'm not sure about this, that's why i told you this.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a note, since I can't comment without 50+ rep...

If you have FIPS enabled on the server, it doesn't allow you to create users. Because IIS v8 (and lower I would imagine) does not use FIPS encryption algorithms. It would be great if it supported it , because obviously a user account in windows is insecure compared to a virtual user mapped to an isolated folder. Too bad.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

in iis manager click directory to protect.

choose authorization rules.

add deny anonymous users rule.

add allow all users rule.

go back to: "in iis manager click directory to protect"
click authentication disable all except basic authentication.

the directory is now protected. only people with user accounts can access the folder over the web.

Comment: I don't know why are you getting downvoted, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

@Colin

"Local Users and Groups" is windows authentication