# No Basic Authentication choice available in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, basic-authentication

I do not have the option for Basic Authentication in IIS Manager under IIS=>Authentication.  I do have the following options:

```
Anonymous Authentication
ASP.NET Impersonation
Forms Authentication
```

I am using Windows 7  professional N, and according to [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753473.aspx), Basic Authentication should be available to me.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Go to Control Panel\Programs -> Turn Windows features on or off, and enable Basic Authentication under IIS:

[image: where]

Comment: to create user password : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373497/how-do-i-create-a-user-account-for-basic-authentication

Comment: And don't forget to go into IIS Manager and actually enable Basic Authentication once you've added it.  (You will need to restart IIS Manager for it to appear).

Comment: It's important to add that you'll likely need to **_close and reopen IIS Manager_** before it will show up in the list of choices for Authentication. (I now have enough rep to add a comment) :)

Comment: It doesn't work!!!!!

Answer (score 53):

I don't have enough rep to add a comment to the chosen answer, but I feel like it's important to add that you'll likely need to ***close and reopen IIS Manager*** before it will show up in the list of choices for Authentication.

Otherwise you could go mad trying to figure out why you did the above and the list didn't change.

Answer (score 41):

> You might have to install the basic authentication module for IIS.
>
> For Vista/Win7 it is: Control Panel -> Programs -> Turn Windows features on or off
>
> For Server 2008: Server Manager -> Roles -> Web Server -> Add Role Services
> Then in the treeview it is: Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Security - > Basic Authentication
>
> Click the checkbox and install. Then you should be able to see the basic authentication option.

(source: https://serverfault.com/questions/29521/iis7-basic-authentication-module-missing)

Comment: This answer covers users of Windows Server 2008 and higher too (since the title doesn't speak of Windows 7 and users can come here from search engines)

Comment: its worth pointing out that you need to right click on web server to get the add role services option