# Password protect ASP.NET web application in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, iis-7.5

I use IIS 7.5 on windows 7 to serve my asp.net websites for testing purposes. In order to stop random people viewing my websites I want IIS to require a username and password before it will serve anything.

I have tried disabling Anonymous Authentication and enabling Windows Authentication on the application but when I type my windows credentials in it doesn't work.

Can somebody explain a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need "Basic Authentication":

> 1. Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager:
>
>    - If you are using Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2008 R2:
>
>      > On the taskbar, click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
>    - If you are using Windows Vista or Windows 7:
>
>      > On the taskbar, click Start, and then click Control Panel.
>      >     Double-click Administrative Tools, and then double-click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
> 2. In the Connections pane, expand the server name, expand Sites, and
>      then click the site, application or Web service for which you want to
>      enable basic authentication.
> 3. Scroll to the Security section in the
>      Home pane, and then double-click Authentication.
> 4. In the Authentication
>      pane, select Basic Authentication, and then, in the Actions pane,
>      click Enable.
> 5. In the Authentication pane, select Anonymous
>      Authentication, and then click Disable in the Actions pane.
>
> [image: Screenshot of above settings]
>
> quoted from [Basic Authentication  How To](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/authentication/basicAuthentication#004)

Comment: how to set username/password and return url ?

Comment: to create user password : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373497/how-do-i-create-a-user-account-for-basic-authentication

Comment: I set it up just like this, but noticed that clicking "Cancel" button on the authentication popup will allow visitor to see site :(
what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

With Colin's anwser, don't forget to install "Basic Authentification" feature in the Roles and Features Assistant : "IIS > WebServer > Security"