# Add security to IIS Web Server

Tags: iis, webserver

I'm developing some web site that run on IIS 7 and can connect to SQL server via php. The problem is I think its not safe because everyone that know my public IP address can freely access my site (the site is not for public, but I need it to be accessible to some people). How can I add security to this website of mine?

I have search for some type of security like authentication in IIS, but I don't know what should be used. Can I just add id and password like when we try to open page for configure router (192.168.0.1) .

Answer (score 0):

You can easily disable anonymous authentication and enable basic authentication in IIS 7 using IIS manager.

Here is a [Technet link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772009(v=ws.10).aspx) and an [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373497/how-do-i-create-a-user-account-for-basic-authentication) with details:

Answer (score 0):

Is it a standalone server or do you run the IIS server on a desktop?
If your the only one who should access your site you could also use Intergrated windows authentication (IWA). IWA is a feature of the IIS Server, so if you wan't to use is you should enable it first.